# How to make side arrow images non-transparent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using Bootstrap's Carousel but with some custom arrow images. They are still showing up transparent, how can I get them to show normally, at full opacity? Some code:

***HTML:***

```
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span>
                <img src="../assets/imgs/arrows.png" />
              </span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span>
                <img src="../assets/imgs/arrows.png" />
              </span>
            </a>
```

***CSS:***

```
.carousel-control .glyphicon,
.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 5;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  font-family: serif;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `opacity: 0;` to `opacity: 1;` in the css.

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap css have some other css class with opacity, try to use the css below:

```
.carousel-control {
  filter: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-control:hover,
.carousel-control:focus {
  filter: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

This worked for you?If it doesnt, post your code at http://jsfiddle.net/ :)